# Why is my custom route registering as a 404?

Tags: form, routes, 404

### The context

I have a URL schema that is either doing something new, via a custom Route (no entry set):

```
bookings/new/*
```

…or reviewing an existing entry:

```
bookings/{slug}
```

My custom route is working fine in that it's routing to the correct template logic when  no entry is set.

I have some development in progress which will get converted to working with the PHP session – and therefore a properly integrated action URL – but for now I'm just invoking a template-derived action URL on a hard-coded `<form>` tag to test front-end behaviours.

### The problem

The template renders fine and the front end behaves fine *in all respects in my **local** dev environment*, but…

*In the **staging** environment only*, something like the following is getting auto-added after my opening form tag (not by any code I have written):

```
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="bookings/new/accommodation">
```

…and the form will not submit to the next stage of the booking path that's invoked by the action URL.

I infer this is because it is determined to be a 404, even though the path matches the custom route and the expected template is being invoked.

As far as I can see the local and staging environments are near identical:

- Both are running 4.3.6, albeit with:

  - Minor differences in host PHP
  - My local dev is Nitro and therefore using `mariadb`
- Both have the same plugins and modules

Any clues as to what is going on?

---

- My bookings channel section has a URI format of `bookings/{slug}` and calls `bookings/_entry`
- My custom route is `bookings/new/*` and calls `bookings/_entry`

---

### Update

This feels like a work-around, not really a fix:

- It seems that when a custom route is registering as a 404 (still don't know why that's the case here), there is a `p` parameter in `craft.app.request.queryParams` even when it is not explicitly in the URL.
- And it was getting rendered because I had…

```
{% set qParams = craft.app.request.queryParams ?? null %}

…

<form …>
    {# Pass params along in the URL but 
       exclude ones that have fields submitted in this page
    #}
    {% set excludes = ['array', 'of', 'names'] %}

    {% for key, val in qParams %}
        {% if key not in excludes %}
            <input type="hidden" name="{{ key }}" value="{{ val }}">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

…so I have tweaked that with:

```
{% for key, val in qParams %}
    {% if key not in excludes and key != 'p' %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ key }}" value="{{ val }}">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

…which works.

### Revised framing of the question

I would still like to know why there is a 404 registering in the first place.

Is it perhaps that when `entry` is not defined that *equates to a 404* even if a custom route picks it up?

Answer (score 1):

You must be running Apache on staging, but not on dev, and the `p` param is getting added by the mod_rewrite rule in `.htaccess`.

`p` is the default [pathParam](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#pathparam) config setting value. When present, it will be used to define the requested URI path.

Comment: Thanks. Staging is Apache and I am running Nitro on dev (haven't got with the DDEV program yet.) So is it the case that when `entry` remains unset there is kind of a soft 404 that persists?

Comment: You lost me there. `entry` will only be set if the template was loaded via a section’s Entry URI Format setting. If the template is assuming `entry` is set then you might get a 500 error, but not a 404.

Comment: No worries. I should probably provide more template context to make it clear what _seems_ to be happening in my environment, but it’s not high priority. So thanks for your time today on this and my other thread.